# How to make html tags act accordingly in flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I working with this api which comes with html tags like

and many more. As the api comes from a blog post it would come with the tags and my boss wants me to show the data accordingly in the flutter app. I tried the flutter_html: ^2.2.1 but doesn't help.

api response:

```
<p>মালিশ একটি অতি প্রচলিত চিকিৎসা পদ্ধতি। গা ব্যথা, কোমর ব্যথা, গিঁটে ব্যথা, এমনকি মাথাব্যাথাতেও &lsquo;বাম&rsquo;  &lsquo;বাম&rsquo; কিংবা মালিশের স্তুতি তুলে ধরতে গিয়ে টিভি বিজ্ঞাপনগুলোও কম যায় না। এসব চটকদার বিজ্ঞাপনে &lsquo;বাম&rsquo;, ঠে, হাতে &ndash;পায়ের তালুতে তেল মালিশের প্রচলন তো রয়েছেই।</p>\r\n\r\n<p>এখন প্রশ্ন হচ্ছে, &lsquo; বাম &lsquo; কিং মাধ্যমে।</p>\r\n\r\n<p>বাম কিংক্যাম্পফর, মেনথল, মিথাইল, স্যালিসাইলেট। এগুলো ত্বকে ঠান্ডা অথবা গরম অনুভূতির উদ্রেগ করে এবং সেই সঙ্গে কিছুটা ব্যথা নিরাময় ও অবশভাব আনে। এতে সাময়িকভাবে ব্যথার উৎস থেকে ব্যথার অনুভূতি অন্যখানে ছড়াতে পারে না।</p>\r\n\r\n<p>সম্ভবত এটা ব্যথার সংকেতের সরাসরি অথবা স্নায়ু উত্তেজিত করে এই  উপশম করে না।</p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>লেখক : সহযোগী অধ্যাপক, হলিফ্যামিলি রেডক্রিসেন্ট মেডিকেল কলেজ</strong></p>
```

Is there any package or method by which I can show the data accordingly like the following:

```html
<p>মালিশ একটি অতি প্রচলিত চিকিৎসা পদ্ধতি। গা ব্যথা, কোমর ব্যথা, গিঁটে ব্যথা, এমনকি মাথাব্যাথাতেও &lsquo;বাম&rsquo;  &lsquo;বাম&rsquo; কিংবা মালিশের স্তুতি তুলে ধরতে গিয়ে টিভি বিজ্ঞাপনগুলোও কম যায় না। এসব চটকদার বিজ্ঞাপনে &lsquo;বাম&rsquo;, ঠে, হাতে &ndash;পায়ের তালুতে তেল মালিশের প্রচলন তো রয়েছেই।</p>\r\n\r\n<p>এখন প্রশ্ন হচ্ছে, &lsquo; বাম &lsquo; কিং মাধ্যমে।</p>\r\n\r\n<p>বাম কিংক্যাম্পফর, মেনথল, মিথাইল, স্যালিসাইলেট। এগুলো ত্বকে ঠান্ডা অথবা গরম অনুভূতির উদ্রেগ করে এবং সেই সঙ্গে কিছুটা ব্যথা নিরাময় ও অবশভাব আনে। এতে সাময়িকভাবে ব্যথার উৎস থেকে ব্যথার অনুভূতি অন্যখানে ছড়াতে পারে না।</p>\r\n\r\n<p>সম্ভবত এটা ব্যথার সংকেতের সরাসরি অথবা স্নায়ু উত্তেজিত করে এই  উপশম করে না।</p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>লেখক : সহযোগী অধ্যাপক, হলিফ্যামিলি রেডক্রিসেন্ট মেডিকেল কলেজ</strong></p>
```

The `\r\n\r\n` should also act accordingly like html tags

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you use RegEx to detect HTML tags and remove them. So you can use each tag correctly.
If you do not know how to use regEx in Flutter, I recommend reading [flutter documents.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)

Answer (score -1):

new HtmlView(
data: html,
baseURL: "", // optional, type String
onLaunchFail: (url) { // optional, type Function
print("launch $url failed");
}